# How can I launch GoAccess in Windows?

Tags: goaccess

I saw [here](https://goaccess.io/download) that GoAccess can be installed on Windows. I would like to use it with ISS 8.5 log files but I cannot find any tutorial about how this can be used in Windows through Cygwin.

Any help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to install [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/install.html). There are a lot of [tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20install%20cygwin) out there on how to do that.

Then you will need to install in cygwin at least the following packages:

```
wget
libGeoIP-devel
libncurses-devel
libncursesw10
gcc-core
make
automake
gettext
```

Then compile GoAccess as indicated in the [download page](https://goaccess.io/download).

```
$ wget http://tar.goaccess.io/goaccess-1.1.1.tar.gz
$ tar -xzvf goaccess-1.1.1.tar.gz
$ cd goaccess-1.1.1/
$ ./configure --enable-geoip --enable-utf8
$ make
# make install
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add my 2 cents, that Windows now ships with an Ubuntu subsystem: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Cygwin is not needed in 2018

Comment: Sadly this is not true for Windows 10 production systems versions as Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSM (the one i use). This one will get this kind of updates next year :-(

Answer (score 0):

You may give our free [CowAxess](https://itefix.net/cowaxess) a try:

**CowAxess** is a *GoAccess* implementation for Windows systems. It is a packaging of *GoAccess*, *Cygwin* and many other related tools to make it a complete and ready-to-use solution for real-time web log analysis, all in a 4 MB package. We have followed standard instructions available at the *GoAccess* website.

*CowAxess* is available as a free solution licensed under simplified BSD. Enjoy!

NB! We are the developer of the solution.